# Is there a way to set maximum and minimum radius for circle in react-google-maps?

Tags: react-google-maps

I'm using `react-google-maps` circle and while changing the circle radius I'm unable to prevent it to the maximum and minimum radius limits, can anyone help me with this, Thank you. and below is my code

```
<Circle
   center={this.circleCenter}
   radius={this.circleRadius}
   draggable={false}
   editable={true}
   ref={circle => { this.circle = circle; }}
   onCenterChanged={(e) => this.onRadiusChange(e)}
   onRadiusChanged={(e) => this.onRadiusChange(e)} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<Circle
       center={this.circleCenter}
       radius={Math.min(Math.max(this.circleRadius, MIN_VALUE), MAX_VALUE)}
       draggable={false}
       editable={true}
       ref={circle => { this.circle = circle; }}
       onCenterChanged={(e) => this.onRadiusChange(e)}
       onRadiusChanged={(e) => this.onRadiusChange(e)} />
```

Comment: Circle radius is not limiting to the minimum and maximum values

Comment: can you extract the radius expression and console log it to make sure it is indeed giving you the expected value? That way you can isolate the issue:

const calculatedRadius = Math.min(Math.max(this.circleRadius, MIN_VALUE), MAX_VALUE)
console.log(calculatedRadius)